# How can I install php7.4 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

After adding the ppa `ondrej/php`, I try `sudo apt-get install php7.4`, but the output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

I have checked and there is a package that should install with that command, but I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` since adding the repo? That package name looks right to me.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that and I've tried apt-get upgrade too which did not change anything either

Comment: same problem, cant install php7.4

Answer (score 43, accepted):

have you tried updating your rep?

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4
php -v
```

I didn't pay enough attention, this package doesn't exist yet for ubuntu 19.04:

```
php7.4  7.4.2-6+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1    Ondrej Surý (2020-02-05)
php7.4  7.4.2-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1    Ondrej Surý (2020-02-05)
php7.4  7.4.2-6+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1    Ondrej Surý (2020-02-05)
```

Comment: I tried that and it still gives me the same error unfortunately.

Comment: updated, i previously missed the ubuntu 19.04 part in your title

Comment: I noticed that, I think that I am going to have to change my version of ubuntu because it is no longer supported

Comment: worked perfectly for ubuntu 21 as well. you saved the day. thanks @AliAdiby