# php 7.4 installation fail - E: Unable to locate package php7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

php installation fail getting this error `E: Unable to locate package php7.4`
ubuntu version **16.04**

i also try

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4
```

but not working

Comment: try `sudo apt -y install php7.4`

Comment: @Regolith getting same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509401/5320802

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install php7.4 on Ubuntu 19.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509312/how-can-i-install-php7-4-on-ubuntu-19-04)