# E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php-7.4'

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1
I am having issues with php version's installation Specially php7.4.
[image]

I have tried with these reference but it did't work for me.

https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-php-7-4-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

[How can I install php7.4 on Ubuntu 19.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509312/how-can-i-install-php7-4-on-ubuntu-19-04)

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/%3A+Unable+to+locate+package+php7.4-fpm

Please help !!!
Thanks.

Comment: run: 
`apt-get update`

then: 
`apt-cahce search php`

what is your output?

Comment: sudo apt-get update:
Err:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***.***.**.**]
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: sudo apt-cache search php :
libgtksourceview-4-common - common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
libnet-libidn-perl - Perl bindings for GNU Libidn

Comment: run the following as root `sudo su - ` then:
`apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base`
then:
`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
then:
`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-qa`
then: `apt-get update`
then: `apt-cahce search php`

Answer (score 5):

Hit the following commands to install php at any version (replace php7.4 with your required version) in Linux OS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install php7.4
```

Check PHP Version :

```
php -v
```

You may need some other packages to install. You can do so by following the commands :

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-json php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-xml php7.4-bcmath
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm
```

Start FPM and check status :

```
systemctl restart php7.4-fpm
systemctl status php7.4-fpm
```

The above-mentioned actions resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**If Still You are Facing below Error (Then Try tricky solution) its not official but worked for me.**

**Error:** Unable to locate package php7.4

**Scenario:** I was using Ubuntu 20 in azure after trying all documents and efforts but couldn't install PHP.

**Solution:** I just replaced **/etc/apt/source.list file content** with fresh Ubuntu 20 **/etc/apt/source.list file content** and then It worked :-)

Reference Docs : https://tech2towards.blogspot.com/2021/12/install-php-older-version-in-ubuntu-16.html